# How to use endpoint inside another endpoint in express node js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am just stuck in a problem and also don't know whether the question is correct or not.

I am working on a node express js, using ejs templating engine.

I have created certain endpoints (say login(POST) endpoint) which are generic endpoints.

Now I want to create a new application which uses should use these endpoints and render the view according to the result of these endpoints.

Lets say I have a generic endpoint for login

```
router.post('/user/login', function (req, res) {
  var userLoginId = req.body.username;
  var currentPassword = req.body.password;

  UserLogin.findOne({userLoginId: userLoginId, currentPassword: currentPassword}, function (err, usr) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error in User login');
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).type('application/problem+json').send();
    } else {
      if (!usr) {
        console.log('Please enter valid username and password');
        res.status(404).type('application/problem+json').send();
      } else {
        res.type('application/json').status(200).send(usr);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And I am using this login.ejs file

```
<div class="container panel panel-primary">
    <h2 class="h2 text-center">Login</h2>
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="loginForm" method="post" action="/user/login">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 control-label">UserName</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now I want to use this code and want to login to the system.

If the user login is successful I want to redirect to dashboard page else same login page.

On executing this code the api returns me the JSON response and from this response how can I decide to whether to redirect on dashboard page or login page.

Please help if more input is needed please put a comment.

Comment: Why would you redirect to the login page again, after the login has failed? After the login has failed you should take the error and provide it to the user, so he can fix it - without reloading the entire page. This is the current state of the art of UX. Upon successful login (so if the http-status is 200 or your return-message contains successful or whatever) you can redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead of doing a form request to login, do a AJAX request to login and then use something like jQuery to do the AJAX request and response. Alternatively you could do something like the following.

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', {});
})

router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var userLoginId = req.body.username;
  var currentPassword = req.body.password;

  UserLogin.findOne({userLoginId: userLoginId, currentPassword: currentPassword}, function (err, usr) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error in User login');
      console.log(err);
      // res.status(500).type('application/problem+json').send();
      res.status(500).render('login', { error : 'Error finding password'})
    } else {
      if (!usr) {
        console.log('Please enter valid username and password');
        // res.status(404).type('application/problem+json').send();
        res.status(404).render('login', { error : 'Please enter valid username and password'})
      } else {
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

For the login.ejs file i would conditionally render the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
    <div class="container panel panel-primary">
        <h2 class="h2 text-center">Login</h2>
        <%if (locals.error) { %>
            <%= error %>
        <% } %>

             <form class="form-horizontal" name="loginForm" method="post" action="/user/login">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username" class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 control-label">UserName</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```